# Swig with anaconda environment on Mac OS throws Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread

Tags: python, anaconda, swig

Swig within anaconda environment on Mac OS throws `Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread`

I'm looking for a solution using swig and conda on Mac OS X.

The code is based on this github example, which works well on Linux 16.04 but fails on Mac OS X

https://github.com/rdeits/swig-eigen-numpy

It works  outside the conda environment, but not inside of it.

This is my current environment `conda list`

```
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0  
bokeh                     0.12.13          py36h2f9c1c0_0  
bzip2                     1.0.6                hd86a083_4  
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0  
certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0  
cffi                      1.11.5           py36h342bebf_0  
chardet                   3.0.4            py36h96c241c_1  
click                     6.7              py36hec950be_0  
cmake                     3.9.4                h30c3106_0  
cryptography              2.2.2            py36h1de35cc_0  
curl                      7.59.0               ha441bb4_0  
cycler                    0.10.0           py36hfc81398_0  
expat                     2.2.5                hb8e80ba_0  
fastdtw                   0.3.2                     <pip>
flask                     0.12.2           py36h5658096_0  
freetype                  2.8                  h12048fb_1  
gcloud                    0.18.3                    <pip>
gevent                    1.2.2            py36ha70b9d6_0  
googleapis-common-protos  1.5.3                     <pip>
greenlet                  0.4.13           py36h1de35cc_0  
httplib2                  0.11.3                    <pip>
idna                      2.6              py36h8628d0a_1  
intel-openmp              2018.0.0                      8  
itsdangerous              0.24             py36h49fbb8d_1  
jinja2                    2.9.6            py36hde4beb4_1  
libcurl                   7.59.0               hf30b1f0_0  
libcxx                    4.0.1                h579ed51_0  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hebd6815_0  
libedit                   3.1                  hb4e282d_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libpng                    1.6.34               he12f830_0  
libssh2                   1.8.0                h322a93b_4  
libuv                     1.20.0               h1de35cc_0  
livereload                2.5.1                     <pip>
markupsafe                1.0              py36h3a1e703_1  
matplotlib                2.0.2            py36h507e440_1  
mkl                       2018.0.2                      1  
ncurses                   6.0                  hd04f020_2  
numpy                     1.13.1           py36h93d791d_2  
oauth2client              4.1.2                     <pip>
openssl                   1.0.2o               h26aff7b_0  
pandas                    0.20.3           py36hd6655d8_2  
patsy                     0.5.0                    py36_0  
pcre                      8.42                 h378b8a2_0  
pip                       9.0.3                    py36_0  
protobuf                  3.5.2.post1               <pip>
pyasn1                    0.4.2                     <pip>
pyasn1-modules            0.2.1                     <pip>
pycparser                 2.18             py36h724b2fc_1  
pyopenssl                 17.5.0           py36h51e4350_0  
pyparsing                 2.2.0            py36hb281f35_0  
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py36_0  
python                    3.6.5                hc167b69_0  
python-dateutil           2.6.1            py36h86d2abb_1  
pytz                      2017.2           py36h2e7dfbc_1  
pyyaml                    3.12             py36h2ba1e63_1  
readline                  7.0                  hc1231fa_4  
requests                  2.18.4           py36h4516966_1  
rhash                     1.3.5                h3aa0507_1  
rsa                       3.4.2                     <pip>
scipy                     1.0.0            py36h1de22e9_0  
setuptools                39.0.1                   py36_0  
six                       1.11.0           py36h0e22d5e_1  
sqlite                    3.23.1               hf1716c9_0  
statsmodels               0.8.0            py36h9c68fc9_0  
swig                      3.0.8                         1  
tk                        8.6.7                h35a86e2_3  
tornado                   5.0.2                    py36_0  
urllib3                   1.22             py36h68b9469_0  
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0  
wheel                     0.31.0                   py36_0  
xz                        5.2.3                h727817e_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
zlib                      1.2.11               hf3cbc9b_2
```

Comment: Verify that the same `python` libraries are used for creating the SWIG module and the running `anaconda` session, use e.g. `ldd`

Comment: @JensMunk i compared the linker command and logged the library loads. It seems to load the same libraries. Strangely it does work with anaconda with python 2.7 but not on 3.6

Comment: It makes sense. You cannot make a `SWIG` library, which both works for 2.7 and 3.6. The `Python` libraries linked to are  different. If you use `CMake`, provide the right version to `find_package(PythonLibs 3.6 REQUIRED)` and `find_package(PythonInterp 3.6 REQUIRED)`

Comment: @JensMunk i figured it out. the python 3.6 binary that ships with anaconda is statically linked with the python libs. Thats why loading a library that dynamically links to them fails due to duplicate symbols. The solution was not to link the library with python libs.

Comment: Glad you made it work. It's the usual CrApple stuff. Let pollute the machine with a bunch of libraries and multiple duplicates instead of conforming to what BSD has used for 30 years :(

Comment: @JensMunk this was actually due Anaconda's team decision to statically link the python library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a pointer to an answer on the anaconda support forum https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/057P4uNWyCU

The python 3.6 binary that ships with anaconda is statically linked with the python libs. Thats why loading a library that dynamically links to them fails due to duplicate symbols. The solution was not to link the library with python libs.

The magic part (it feels like a workaround) is in the SwigPython.cmake file

```
if(APPLE)
    swig_link_libraries(${target} ${swigpy_LINK_LIBRARIES})
    set_target_properties(${SWIG_MODULE_${target}_REAL_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-undefined dynamic_lookup")
else()
    swig_link_libraries(${target} ${swigpy_LINK_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```